# Rails 4 - how to trigger Object edit form without refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi and thanks for looking into this.

I have a list of objects displayed on my page. Now when a user selects one of the objects, I'd like to show Edit form for this object without refreshing the page and allow user to update it. I already have a form partial with :remote tag. What I cannot figure out is how to trigger this Edit form and pass the correct object into it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the form partial for each item in an hidden div, and show the div with javascript only when needed :

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div>
    <%= item.label %>
    <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a>
    <div class="editFormWrapper">
      <%= render '_form', locals: {item: item} %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

css:

```
.editFormWrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

javascript (with jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editLink').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('editFormWrapper').show();  // or .slideDown(); or any other effect
  });
});
```

If the page contains a lot of items, or if the hidden form is big, it may be better to use Ajax to request and include the edit form "on demand", to keep the weight of the page to minimum.

Comment: Thanks @Baldrick. I followed your suggestion and already did it using jQuery .ajax() method. Just passing the ID of the object and requesting edit form for it, then render it within the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you render page with objects, you can render objects array in javascript variable

```
<script>
OBJ_ARR = {
  *obj_id1* = {
    name: 'test1',
    desc: 'test test'
  },
  *obj_id2* = {
    name: 'test2',
    desc: 'test2 test'
  },
  ......
}
</scpipt>
```

Next we use javascript scenario
When object clicked you get certain object_id, and then you get appropriate object from our array

```
OBJ_ARR[object_id]
```

So, we put object properties to form and display that form